# How to create a middleware on controller level in spring boot java?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to create a middleware when request comes on controller like we did in express Nodejs.

```
var myLogger = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('LOGGED')
  next()
}
app.use(myLogger)
api.post('/', function(req,res) {
  // enter code here...
})
```

Is it possible in spring boot doing the same functionality
Like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
private class TestApiMiddleware {
  // middleware...
  @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected list() throws Exception {
        // code...
    }
}
```

Comment: These are called Interceptors in Spring

Comment: This is what you are looking for
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor

Comment: The link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a Filter as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class FilterConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Filter loggerFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
            @Override
            public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
                logger.info("LOGGED");
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

}
```